# Nested span inside of a css class

Tags: css, sass, sencha-touch

I am coding a dynamic form with required validation fields, currently I have a parent class called `errorRequired`, with a nested class called `x-form-label`and inside of this class a span with the text, It is working correctly my css rules except in `span` I would like to change the color to red...

```
.errorRequired {
  font-style: oblique;
  color: $mweb-colour-red;
  >.x-form-label{
    &span {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

And compiled CSS

```
.errorRequired{
  font-style:oblique;
  color:red
}
.errorRequired span{color:red}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: We need to see your html as well. Post an example on something like codepen.io (this supports sass).

Comment: I think problem could be how to manage Sencha Touch the tags..  :-|

Comment: post an example with just the html and css. get that working, then add in your js library and we'll see if that breaks it.

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only post the compiled CSS** (and the necessary HTML to reproduce the problem).

Comment: That Sass does not compile to that CSS, and you didn't provide any HTML to go with it.  If you want help debugging, you need to provide an [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

You have the span directly next to the ampersand, which will append 'span' to the class of the 'x-form-label'. This will output the selector as `.errorRequired > .xform-labelspan`.

You don't actually need the ampersand, so try this instead:

```
.errorRequired {
  font-style: oblique;
  color: $mweb-colour-red;
  >.x-form-label{
    span {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

the span selector should then output as `.errorRequired > .xform-label span`

Answer (score 0):

You must use & instead >.

```
.errorRequired {
  font-style: oblique;
  color: $mweb-colour-red;
  & .x-form-label{ /* here, I changed > to & */
    &span {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
.x-form-label {
    .errorRequired & span {
       color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try another strategy: .x-form-label { .errorRequired & span {} }